# jQuery drop down menu in a website using frames

Tags: jquery, frames, drop-down-menu

I'm having to develop a website using frames (Retro) and the client wants a jQuery mega drop down in the header.

The problem I'm having is that the header frame is only about 150px high and the drop down is obviously a lot bigger than that so the majority of it is lost within the frame.

It might be easier to show an example - http://deanelliott.me/misc/saab/index.html (Click the "Categories" link)

I have very little experience with frames so I'm not really sure the best way to get around this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What you are using frames ? whats wrong with positioned divs ?

Comment: What are you asking? *(also, why are you forced to use frames?)*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not iframes ... frames as in `<frameset>` !

Comment: The client insists on using frames. I suggested divs but it was a no go

Comment: @ManseUK Good job you are paying attention :)